# How to install a Progressive Web App on a mobile device?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Im using an iPhone to browser thru various PWA demos online.
Is the installation as simple as adding the URL to the Home Screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as of today, iOS lacks proper support for PWAs, so you won't get any PWA-specific benefits of adding the Web app that is a PWA to the Home Screen on your iPhone. Basically, yes, you will have a shortcut on your Home Screen, but it wouldn't give you any Service Worker capabilities and also your users will never be prompted to add the app to the Home Screen automatically.

On iOS there is only a non-standard Apple solution with meta tags available that allows you to customize the appearance of your website when added to the Home Screen to some extent. See [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html).

See [What Web Can Do](https://whatwebcando.today/installation.html) and [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=web-app-manifest).

**UPDATE Jun 2018**: As of Safari 11.3, iOS supports PWA installation and Service Worker features. However it does not prompt for installation, so the only way to "install" a PWA is to use good old "add to home screen" menu link. Also, it still does not support Service Worker-based Push messaging.

Comment: What about using Chrome on iPhone? Would that give us full PWA experience on an iPhone or is Apple blocking the experience at iOS level?

Comment: No, it will not. Chrome on iPhone is using Webkit underneath, because Apple doesn't allow other vendors to run their browser engines on iOS. Chrome on iOS is just a wrapper for the same technology Safari is using on, so no PWA.

Comment: Wow! So PWA on iOS is a non-starter for now. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Agree with what NOtherDev has mentioned.  But but you can "tell" your users how to add the website to the homescreen if that is one of the requirements.  You just need to design a native looking banner something similar to what Android is doing and detect which device the user is using in order to show the "simulated banner."  Its still a small step for PWA.:)

Comment: With ios 11, you can now add PWAs to your homescreen and use the service worker's abilities, except push notifications. Can you please update your answer? ;)